# view detail in new page when click button using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to display the clicked row button details info in next view,I am displayin only code,nom in first page and remaining fields will view after clicking button. 
I used the option "filter" to do it, but sometimes it returns details of non concerned code , like for the two codes: 45 and 453 , it gaves the same detail because of the common number '45'.

First html page:

```
<div class="row header">

          <div class="col" >Code</div>
          <div class="col">Client</div>        
</div>

<div class="row" ng-repeat="x in namesC">
          <div class="coll"> 
             <a class="button" href="#/detail/{{x.Code}}">
             {{x.Code}}</a> 
          </div>
          <div class="col"> {{x.NomClient}}  </div>              
</div>
```

second html page (detail.html):

```
 <ion-list ng-repeat="x in namesC| filter: {Code: thisX}|limitTo:1"> 

          <ion-item> 
          <div class="item item-divider center-text"> {{x.Code}}</div>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item>
          <b>adresse</b> <span class="item-note">  {{x.adresse}} </span>
          </ion-item>
 </ion-list>
```

app.js :

```
 $stateProvider.state('detailColis', {
            url: '/detail/:Code',
            templateUrl: 'templates/detail.html',
            controller: 'SuiviAdminCtrl' 
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the solution, Thanks to Sudarshan_SMD
The solution is just to change filter: with :

```
filter: {CodeEnvoiColis: thisX}:true
```

Answer (score 0):

You must add Config file Or add the down code in html file to solve this problem

```
<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl : "main.htm"
    })
    .when("/detail/:Id", {
        templateUrl : "detail.htm"
    })

});
</script>
```

I tested the above code, its working.

Comment: Thank you, but I already did this code, and when I click on the button , it generates the view details, but not those of the selected row

Comment: Oh,Ok You Must Add Id to Url So take the recorde ID and view details those the selected row

Comment: I will Edit the Code Above

Comment: yes, this is what I did:  $stateProvider.state('detail', {
            url: '/detail/:Code',
            templateUrl: 'templates/detail.html',
            controller: 'SuiviAdminCtrl' 
        });

Comment: You Must Add Method in controller take $stateProvider.Id and return the data determind on this Id.

Comment: thank you, but I did this, and no change, (Code is my Id). sometimes I get the details of the row I want , but when I have for exemple these two codes (45 and 456 I get the same details)

Comment: Can You Add the Code in Controler and Api To I Show What is the problem.

Comment: In the controller, I have just the function "load", just to load data from database, from where I get data in the two views

Comment: $scope.load = function(){ 
              $http.get("http://localhost/deb/select.php")  
           .success(function(data){  
                $scope.thisX   =  $state.params.Code; 
                $scope.namesC = data;  
           });

           }

Comment: How can I do please!

Comment: For $http.get requests use the params property of the config object $http.get(url, {params:{ Id:$stateProvider.Id}}).then(func....

Comment: Why not use the General code of AngularJs to do build the Controler and DataFactory and API ,to connect to DataBase

Comment: because I have to work with it in the netbook Specifications! thank you for your help, but unfortunately it doesn't work !

Comment: This code is Working with me                                                                                                                    
  var Code = $stateProvider.Id;                                                 $http.get(url, { Id:Code}).then(func....

Answer (score 0):

We can use `$routeParams`, Also we can use service. See basic example and try like below.

```js
var app = angular.module('exApp',['ngRoute']);
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
$routeProvider
.when('/', {
template:'<p>All Datas View</p><p ng-repeat="data in datas">{{data.name}}    <button ng-click="setData(data)">View</button> routeParams..   <button ng-click="setrouteData($index)">Index</button></p>',
 controller: 'ctrl',
})
.when('/detail',{template:'<p>Particular Data View</p><button ng-click="back()">Back</button><br><p>{{data}}</p>',controller: 'ctrlOne'})
 .when('/detail/:id',{template:'<p>Data View</p><button ng-click="back()">Back</button><br><p>{{data}}</p>',
 controller: 'ctrltwo'})
.otherwise({redirectTo:'/'});
}]);

app.controller('ctrl', function($scope,$location,exService){
$scope.datas = exService.data;
$scope.setData = function(data){
//console.log(data);
exService.Obj = data;
$location.path('detail');
}
$scope.setrouteData = function(index){
$location.path('detail/'+ index);
}
});

app.controller('ctrlOne', function($scope,$location, exService){
var data = exService.Obj;
$scope.data=data;
$scope.back = function(){
$location.path('/');
}
});

app.controller('ctrltwo', function($scope,$location, $routeParams,exService){
var data = $routeParams.id; 
$scope.datas = exService.data;
$scope.data=$scope.datas[data];
$scope.back = function(){
$location.path('/');
}
});

app.service('exService', function(){
var Obj = {};
var data = [{"id":1, "name":"xxx"},{"id":2, "name":"yyy"},{"id":3, "name":"zzz"}];
return { Obj, data};
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="exApp">
<p>Sample</p>
<div ng-view></div>
</body>
```